# Proper Word-Wrap Functionality

Tags: java, text

As a beginner project I am making a simple text based game that runs in the console of my IDE. I am trying to make messages appear in "boxes" which essentially is just the message being word wrapped and surrounded by an ASCII border.

I succeeded in wrapping the text and adding a border, but my word wrap is very inconvenient. The sentence breakage and continuity is inconvenient (sentences new lines starting on a space or punctuation).

```
public static void msg(String core) {
    int lines = core.length()/100;
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        String part = core.substring((i*100), ((i+1)*100));
        System.out.println("|| " + part + " ||");
    }
    String leftOver = core.substring(lines*100);
    System.out.print("|| " + leftOver);
    for(int i = 0; i < (100 - leftOver.length()); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ||");
    msgBreaker();
}
```

Using the Pacer-Gram fitness test script as a placeholder, this is what can be produced:

[Result Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ongSm.png)

I am okay with words being cut off and continuing on the next line, but I would rather lines not begin with awkward spaces or punctuation that destroy the vertical unity. In other words, the first three lines are fine, but the last three need adjustment.

I am asking for the simplest or most efficient way to handle this. All of the ways I can think of handling this would be overly-sophisticated (for loops with nested if statements) and probably have a performance impact on the game.

Thank you!

Comment: Personally I would use `String.split` and split on white-space.  Then build up a StringBuilder, and only add to it if the length does not exceed 100

Comment: That would destroy any whitespace the OP might have in his strings (like for example tabs and newlines).  Depends on the use-case, but I thought I'd point that out.